# Question at probability with lamps...

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is huge hall that light by $m$ lamps. Every day, start from today, the probability that some lamp will burn is: $p$ (independent).
If a lamp was burn no one replace it.

We mark at $S_n$ the number of the number of the normal lamps (that are unburned)  at the start of day $n$ from today (e.g. $S_1=m$).
$X$ Is random variable. $X$ = the **smallest** natural $n$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$) so that $S_n=0$. (if I understand it right, so it's means that all the lamps will be burned).

**What is the probability function of $X$?**

I'll glad to get some hints...

Thank you!

Comment: Can you work out the probability that all $m$ lamps are burned out on the $k$th day? From that information, can you work out the probability that day $n$ is the first day when all $m$ lamps are burned out?

Comment: @GregMartin, this is where I stuck, I'm really don't know how to figure it out...

Comment: Ok: if there were just a single lamp, what's the probability that it's burned out on the $k$th day? (It's probably easier to calculate the probability that it's not burned out on the $k$th day, since that's just the same outcome happening $k$ times in a row.)

Comment: @GregMartin, it's $(p)^k$? Thank you!

Comment: How does it helps me???

Answer (score 2):

We're assuming that the lamps are all independent of one another, and that a burned-out lamp stays burned out but otherwise every lamp has an independent probability of $p$ of burning out on any given day.

For an individual lamp, the only way it stays lit through $k$ days is if it avoids $k$ independent burnout attempts. The probability of this happening is $(1-p)^k$. Therefore the probability of an individual lamp being burned out by the $k$th day is $1-(1-p)^k$.

The $m$ lamps are all independent, so the probability of all $m$ lamps being burned out by the $k$th day is $\big(1-(1-p)^k\big)^m$.

Finally, $X=n$ if and only if the lamps are all burned out by the $n$th day but not all burned out by the $(n-1)$st day. Since being all burned out by the $(n-1)$st day is a subevent of being burned out by the $n$th day, we can simply subtract probabilities to see that
$$
\Pr(X=n) = \big(1-(1-p)^n\big)^m - \big(1-(1-p)^{n-1}\big)^m.
$$

Comment: Why $1-p$? We have to calculate the probability that all the lamps will burn, and the probability of it it's $p$.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding this solution, pretend for a while that there's only one lamp ($m=1$). If the trouble is earlier on, go through the second paragraph specifically when $k=1$ and make sure you understand it. Then go through it again when $k=2$; if you see that, you'll probably see it for all $k$.

Comment: I liked your solution and I find it very intuitive as well. Personally, did not come up with it, although I tried...

Comment: This what I did... and I still not understand why it's $(1-p)^k$ and not $p^k$... Thank you!

Comment: $p$ is the probability that the lamp burns out on a given day. So $p^k$ would be the probability that the lamp burns out repeatedly on days 1, 2, ..., $k$.